# How do I sync audio and movement on my NXT 2.0?

Tags: nxt, programming, motor, software, electronics

How do I sync audio and movement with my NXT 2.0? I'm building an animatronic head and I can't find a good way to sync it with external audio because the internal speaker is too quiet.

Comment: How long is your audio, what type of device are you using to play external audio and is there anything you have tried so far in regards to syncing?

Comment: Its pretty short audio, maybe only a few seconds. I did try having the audio play from the internal speaker but it was really quiet and the movements wouldn't sync up with the movements.

Comment: Is this playing through a computer or a device showing a screen?